# Regular Expression match ID in ClientId

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression in my code to match on the keys (control ClientId) within a form POST. I am looping round all the keys in the form data and performing the required action when a match is found.

However the regex is matching more times than I need it to. This runs on every request and if performing unnecessary code to fire.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(key.ToLower(), @"(?!\$)(?:[a-z0-9]+)$",
                          RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Sample string that are coreectly matching

```
master$maincontentplaceholder$ucsearchresults$hdnvalue
master$maincontentplaceholder$ucsearchresults$hdnvalue2
master$maincontentplaceholder$ucsearchresults$hdnvalue3
```

I then have a switch statment with cases matching the control id

```
case: "hdnvalue"
case: "hdnvalue2"
case: "hdnvalue3"
```

The form is also returning a large number of extra keys that do not always require processing. It would be good if I could exclude these from being matched within the regex. (note the extra client id level `$ucfilter`)

```
master$maincontentplaceholder$ucsearchresults$ucfilter$hdnvalue
master$maincontentplaceholder$ucsearchresults$ucfilter$hdnvalue2
master$maincontentplaceholder$ucsearchresults$ucfilter$hdnvalue3
```

Comment: Why don't you create a conditional logic to filter the control id's you want to work with, instead of trying to do everything with Regex. As long ad your Regex matches includes the correct id's, filtering the regex results will just be fine, isn't it?!

Comment: I think your probably right flowerking, in trying to attempt the above im only making it harder for myself. I have also just noticed the extra keys values are empty so can be excluded by testing on the post value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't /have/ to use regex, you might do better with LastIndexOf("$")

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "master$maincontentplaceholder$ucsearchresults$ucfilter$hdnvalue";
            string id = text.Substring(text.LastIndexOf("$") + 1);
            Console.WriteLine(id);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to describe more formally accepted format, this regex will pass the criteria you have given:

```
^([a-z0-9]+\$){3}[a-z0-9]+$
```